# Deleting first row and column in excel using python (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to delete the first row and the first column in excel files using pandas. On the left it can be seen what i have and on the right what i want:

*excel*
[image: excel]

I have been using pandas to transpose the values (this works) and after that to delete the first row and column. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'ex1.xlsx'

sheets = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)  
sheet_name, df = next(iter(sheets.items()))         
df = df.T                                        
df = df.drop(0, axis = 1)                           
df = df.drop(0, axis = 0)                           
df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name)
```

The first drop does not give back an error, but does not do anything in the excel file (it does not delete the first column. The second drop gives back an error *[0] not found in axis*.

What am i doing wrong? Why do i get this error and why does the first drop do nothing?

Comment: what is `print (df.columns)` and `print(df.index)` after `sheet_name, df = next(iter(sheets.items()))` ?

Answer (score 0):

If first row are columns names and first column are index values use:

```
sheets = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)  
sheet_name, df = next(iter(sheets.items()))
```

Test index and columns:

```
print (df.columns)
print(df.index)
```

---

```
df = df.T                                        
                       
df.to_excel(file_name, sheet_name, index=False, header=False)
```